# MetaMask transaction popup opens on another computer

Tags: web3js, metamask, dapp-development, dapps, meta-transactions

We have two computers on the same local network with Static IP for internet. When Computer A calls a transaction through a DApp for an address X, Computer B Metamask is also getting triggered with the same transaction.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an issue with metamask, I think you need to try removing the browser-sync from the node-modules.

Comment: removing the browser-sync didnt help.